# Analog '90s? staff on abandoned alien space station infected with religion meme

Tags: story-identification, aliens, religion

I've been looking for this story for a long time.

I believe it was published in *Analog Science Fiction* in the 1990's. In the story, an abandoned alien space station has been discovered at another star system. I vaguely recall this is the second or third mission to the space station. Perhaps the first mission staff all died. As the current mission staff explore the station they are infected with a religion meme that includes an elaborate ritual that (really fuzzy memory here) includes a sacrifice.

One character makes a comment about the last time it took 2000 years to extinguish this meme.

Comment: do you have anymore information about the story?

Comment: You could explain about "staff on an abandoned space station" for a start. I mean, if there's a staff, it isn't abandoned!

Comment: [Sounds familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reason_(short_story))

Comment: @Richard: I ran into that one on my searches too, but I figured he would have mentioned it if it were a robot.

Comment: I came across [Unitology](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Unitology)

Comment: The staff is of an interstellar expedition. They may be the second or third team to explore the old alien station. Whoops. Just realized I didn't mention "alien" in the original question. My apology. As I recall the story, the meme-infected staff were performing a religious ritual that involved human sacrifice (I think). This stuck in my memory because it was the first time I remember reading a SF story that took a really negative view of Christianity and defined it as a meme. An early harbinger perhaps.

Comment: I agree on the date, but believe that it was in *Fantasy and Science Fiction Magazine. I think the base was in the Oort Cloud, that humanity has discovered lots of interesting stuff there, and that exploration is a huge project — but that infectious memes are a known problem.
The captain of a visiting supply ship realizes that the explorers have gone mad, and destroys the base and the explorers with it, even though this means killing his own crew.
He realizes he could only have made that decision because he was himself infected. He orders the AI to take the ship home, and commits suicide.